# Is there anything canon in the Terminator Universe that picks up where Terminator: The Sarah Connors Chronicles leaves off?

Tags: canon, the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

So, Terminator canon is pretty twisted, given all that time-travel stuff.  But in the canon that includes the T:SCC, does anything pick up where the show left off that is considered canon?

Comment: The Sarah Connor Chronicles isn't canon...

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar - I took "in the canon that includes the T:SCC" to mean talking about an expanded canon that goes beyond movie canon--many franchises have different levels of canon, like Star Wars with movie canon vs. EU canon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there aren't any authorized books or comics continuing TSCC, and there don't seem to be plans for any, canon or not.

Comment: Thats disappointing.  I just rewatched it again and really enjoyed it...sigh.

Comment: I wish someone like Amazon or Netflix would fund the sequels!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no. I forget where I saw it, but the timeline of TSCC is just sort of forgotten and ignored in T4 and I am assuming in the new one they are planning as well. It really is disappointing that they do that, as TSCC finished on such a "What happened?" note, that even if they were to have a tie in with it, it would really help. Let's face it, the timeline presented in TSCC was better than that in T3... and not even a contest with the unwatchable garbage of T4...

Comment: The last part of your answer ventures into opinion territory.